# Replacing a String within a JS file and not breaking sourceMaps in brunch

Tags: javascript, source-maps, brunch

I need to replace a String `someString` by another `anotherString` in my JS files, e.g.

```
function someString() { ... }
```

should become

```
function anotherString() { ... }
```

in brunch (can be pre- or post-compilation, however I would like to avoid copying all files to a temporary location).

Running this in `onCompile` works, however it seems to break sourceMaps (because the Strings are not the same length).

Is there a sourceMap-safe way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same question and wrote this little script:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/sourcemap-aware-replace

usage:

```
sourcemap-aware-replace --search=foo --replace=barr --in-map=test.js.map --out-file=test.replaced.js
```